# Excel Power Query Close & Load Format

Tags: excel, powerquery

When I run a query in MS Excel, and return the data to the worksheet, it always returns the data in font Helv 7. This format also affects the format of the row numbers & column headers. My default font/size is Calibri 11. I've looked all over and I can't seem to find any setups to change.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then edit your question to provide more information.  Or you could upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem (with sensitive information removed) to some public sharing site, and post a link in your edited question.

Comment: I uploaded a file to dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/s/4mmgj4rf2w0bofr/Example.xlsx?dl=0       You can see on the "Query Results" tab the tiny font that was returned, even though the original data is in Calibri 10

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your workbook and the problem has nothing to do with Power Query.  **Any** newly created sheet will have a font of Helvetica 7.

The problem is due to your "Normal" style which has been changed.

[image]

Right click on the Style box, select Modify; then Format; and change the font format to whatever you want for a new worksheet.

[image]

[image]

If you do this on the sheet that contains the query result, the font will change on that sheet (but not on other sheets that have previously been created).

Comment: THANK YOU! I figured there was some sort of setup that got screwed up!